# Computing minimum and maximum excess of byte over binary function

Tags: c++, function, binary, pattern-matching

I have a function `PI (input 0 or 1)`, which gives `PI[0] = -1, PI[1] = 1`.

Given a byte B, I would like to have a function computing the minimum excess over PI from left to right. Similarly, I need a function computing the maximum excess over PI from left to right. Example:

```
PI_MIN[0] = -8, PI_MAX[0] = -1

PI_MIN[1] = -7, PI_MAX[1] = -1

PI_MIN[2] = -6, PI_MAX[2] = -1

PI_MIN[3] = -6, PI_MAX[3] = -1
```

At the moment I precompute the function values, store these in a universal table, and access it at runtime. Or alternatively I compute the result naively (for loop over bits). For `PI_MIN` and `PI_MAX` we have:

`static constexpr int8_t PI_MIN[] { -8, -7, -6, -6, -6, -5, -5, -5, -6, -5, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4,
    -4, -6, -5, -4, -4, -4, -3, -3, -3, -4, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -6, -5, -4, -4, -4, -3, -3, -3, -4, -3, -2, -2,
    -2, -2, -2, -2, -4, -3, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -6, -5, -4, -4, -4, -3, -3, -3, -4,
    -3, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -4, -3, -2, -2, -2, -1, -1, -1, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -4, -3, -2, -2, -2, -1,
    -1, -1, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -6, -5, -4,
    -4, -4, -3, -3, -3, -4, -3, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -4, -3, -2, -2, -2, -1, -1, -1, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
    -4, -3, -2, -2, -2, -1, -1, -1, -2, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -4, -3,
    -2, -2, -2, -1, -1, -1, -2, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -2, -1, 0, 0, 0,
    1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };`

`static constexpr int8_t PI_MAX[] { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
    0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
    2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4,
    4, 5, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
    2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 4, 4,
    4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8 };`

Unfortunately I couldn't find a pattern for all functions I need to use (e.g. `PI_MIN, PI_MAX`, but there is more). The question is: how can I find out whether a function exists which can compute this in a non-naive way (i.e., no for loop from left to right in the input byte). My goal is to reach maximum performance, since this function is in the inner-most loop of a larger program.

I'm thankful for any hints!

Comment: Maximum performance would be your table lookup, would it not? And your definition of PI_MIN and PI_MAX are not at all clear to me.

Comment: The table lookup is bad when you have a cache miss, I need a function avoiding memory accesses. PI_MAX is the maximal sum over PI you can get over a byte, PI_MIN the minimal sum. Think of the input as bytes, i.e. 00000000, 00000001, 00000010, 00000011, etc

Comment: What does "minimum excess over PI" mean?

Comment: Given a byte B with bits b0, b1,..,b7, where b0 is the most significant bit, you compute the sum PI[b0], then PI[b0]+PI[b1], then PI[b0]+PI[b1]+PI[b2], etc until you have PI[b0]+..+PI[b7]. The maximal value you get is PI_MAX[B], the minimal value you get is PI_MIN[B]. E.g. for B = 0, PI_MIN[0] = -8, since PI[b0] + PI[b1] + .. + PI[b7] is smaller than all other sums you may compute over B

Comment: @user46317, That clarifies it immensely. Thanks. In that case, are you not just counting the 0's and 1's in the byte?

Comment: Ignore the confusion about counting bits. You have exactly 8 sums, correct?

Comment: There are 8 possible sums for each function and for each input byte, correct

Comment: It's related to the succinct representation of hierarchies, as background information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A non-branching version of pi_min (assuming the loop is unrolled).

```
/*
  Calculate:
    min(
      pi(b7),
      pi(b7)+pi(b6),
      pi(b7)+pi(b6)+pi(b5),
      pi(b7)+pi(b6)+pi(b5)+pi(b4),
      pi(b7)+pi(b6)+pi(b5)+pi(b4)+pi(b3),
      pi(b7)+pi(b6)+pi(b5)+pi(b4)+pi(b3)+pi(b2),
      pi(b7)+pi(b6)+pi(b5)+pi(b4)+pi(b3)+pi(b2)+pi(b1),
      pi(b7)+pi(b6)+pi(b5)+pi(b4)+pi(b3)+pi(b2)+pi(b1)+pi(b0))

  Where,
    pi(b) = b ? 1 : -1
  and bits in byte b are numbered with the least significant bit (LSB) as 0.

  This problem is essentially one of counting leading zeros where a string
  of leading zeros may be interrupted by a one if it is eventually followed
  by a zero. What happens if there are no leading zeros, then the count is -1.

  The algorithm uses two stacks, "c0" and "c1". c0 is the leading zero count
  and c1 is a stack of potentially intervening 1's.

  foreach bit (following 4 cases are mutually exclusive, only 1 will execute)
    0: if the '1' stack is empty => push a '0' onto the '0' stack
    0: if the '1' stack is not empty => pop a '1' 
    1: if the first bit is a '1' => put the '0' stack in underflow state
    1: if it is not the first bit => push a '1' onto the '1' stack
  return -c0 because zeros actually count as -1
*/
int pi_min(uint8_t byte) {
  int c0 = 0;
  int c1 = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    uint8_t b = !!(byte & (1 << (7-i)));
    c0 -= (b & (i == 0));
    c0 += ((!b) & (0 >= c1));
    c1 -= ((!b) & (0 < c1));
    c1 += (b & (i != 0));
  }
  return -c0;
}

int pi_max(uint8_t byte) { return -pi_min(~byte); }

// The obvious version for comparison.
int pi(uint8_t bit) { return bit ? 1 : -1; }

int pi_min_simple(uint8_t byte) {
  int sum = 0;
  int m = 9;

  for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    uint8_t b = byte & (1 << (7-i));
    sum += pi(b);
    m = std::min(m, sum);
  }
  return m;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your approach, I will give it a try as soon as possible! The function for computing the maximum sum will be similar or analogous, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes. Counting 1's instead of 0's. Answer updated with `pi_max`. Let us know how your performance measurements turn out.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay, I have measured the performance of the different methods now.

http://s12.postimg.org/v400xibxp/prefix_Sums.png

I am very glad to see that the solution suggested by Adam Burry is very efficient (the yellow line). As you can see, even the naive algorithm is slightly faster than the table lookup (green and brown lines) for both minimum and maximum prefix sum computation, which are indeed very similar... The most surprising thing (at least for me) is the terrible performance of maxExcess (which simply returned `-pi_min(~byte)`, as Adam Burry suggested, where pi_min is the function representing the yellow  line). I guess that it has to do with the additional  overhead to compute the binary complement of each and every byte being analyzed, so I will switch to the original algorithm (pi_min) and return -c1 instead to implement pi_max.

Comment: This version is more clear, min and max prefix computation using the table and not using the table (Adam Burrys approach instead, returning -p1 for max variant): http://s22.postimg.org/wnzm5yjlt/prefix_Sums.png

Comment: What compiler, compiler version, and flags are you using? The result for my one-line version of pi_max is also very surprising to me. There should be no function call overhead because I would expect it to be inlined.

Comment: g++ -c -fno-builtin -fno-rtti -std=gnu++11 -march=native -msse -msse2avx -DNDEBUG ..., the g++ version I use is 4.8.1. No function call overhead in my case, I have verified that the function is inlined in the generated code. I will try out icc this week if I have time